# Host saves new css file but displays old one?

Tags: html, css, hosting

------------- **OLD** -----------------

I have a website on byethost where I've transfered my local website to.

The index background image appears locally, but not on the website. How come if I uploaded the files there?

I've checked the path and it's, correct.
The image is not missing.

------------- **EDIT** -----------------

I fount out that the css file has this code:

```
    background-image: url('../images/fundoIndex.jpg');
```

But the code displayed in the console is:

```
    background-image: url('../images/fundoIndex.png');
```

Even tho I've changed it and it's saved, the host sends the old css file for display.. why?

Comment: is your server set up to serve the image mime type?  does the site have permissions to read the image?  Could be a number of reasons but it is impossible to tell from the information you have provided.  Probably should ask your hosting company

Comment: Can you please provide the site URL ?

Comment: It shows background images from other files.. http://joanaferrao.byethost22.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your image is not rendering because you have set the file extension for your background image as "PNG" when it should actually be "JPG".

So...

```
body { background-image: url('../images/fundoIndex.png'); }
```

should be...

```
body { background-image: url('../images/fundoIndex.jpg'); }
```

Comment: the image extension is jpg

Comment: When I inspected your website, the  `<body>` background image has a file extention of .png.  When I changed it to .jpg I got an image of a mobile phone and laptop.  So I'd check your code if I were you because it's pointing to the wrong place.

Comment: Have you uploaded the your updated CSS file and cleared your browser cache?

Comment: Yes, I think the problem might be the server because it happens the same thing when I open in incognito mode, and when I check the file on the host cpanel it says .jpg... but when I open the page it's png..

Comment: It's now displaying the correct image for me now. So if you haven't made any changes I'm inclined to think it's a delay in the changes being propagated to the server.

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that your css file is in a separate folder than your index file. Take it out of that folder & see it that helps.

Also, try changing the name of your image. You have the word index capitalized in the name of the image. Linux servers are case sensitive so no caps on any names. This happened to me before & the fix was as simple as changing from uppercase to lowercase. I hope this helps!

Comment: I'd like to keep the organization.. and even if I change the name, I woun't be able to access it, becausa the file doesnt update